# Physical to Virtual Migration of SharePoint Machine

Tags: migration, stsadm, export, import, virtual-machine

We are about to conduct a full virtual migration. Among the physical machines to be migrated is our SharePoint server, which hosts two SP sites. I know very little about SharePoint and I've only delved into tools like `STSADM` to solve pressing issues in the past since SharePoint is not really in my job duties (but I am stuck with it anyway).

I used to VMWare Converter tool to perform a clone of the existing SP machine *while it was running*. When I imported that image into our virtual environment, everything seemed to be working fine at first. The login page appeared for both sites.

However, when I actually try to login to either site... I can't. It doesn't fail with an error, it just tells me that the username/password is incorrect.

So, I figure that it was wrong for me to run the converter tool while SharePoint was still running. I get that - but instead of bringing the whole image over next time after stopping SharePoint, I'd rather just import/export the data/databases I need.

I tried simply exporting/importing using `STSADM` but it was a fail - there were like 90 warnings and at least 1 error. My suspicion is that I need to import the database(s) but I do not know where to look.

Guidance is highly appreeciated!

Comment: Are your databases on the same server? If not, then you shouldn't run SharePoint from two servers (hardware and virtual), connecting to same database instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to export/import the DBs, you need to install new SharePoint server, and then attach the content DBs, possibly also other DBs, depending what functionalities you have used in SharePoint.

I would investigate the login issue as there should be no reason why virtual migration wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, make sure your old servers are shut off.  T

So the site is actually up and running on the new virtual server?  And you can ping it?  If so, I would look into the time on your new Sharepoint VM.  This is something I've run into far too often and overlook.  Time differences throwing off domain controllers.  Just a thought.

If you actually have the site up, most likely you're just fine as far as the VMWare conversion.  That's not 100% fact, but you're probably out of the woods.  Can you get logged into the local Sharepoint server itself?

Answer (score 0):

Due to timer job sync, if you have more than one SharePoint Server, or the SQL Server is hosted on a different machine, make sure you turn off the SharePoint Server prior to the P2V.  You probably want to do this even on a single-server setup, however.

And of course, make sure DNS is correct, and the old machine is off :)